# Evitar ejecutar código PHP directamente en el navegador

Tags: php

Tengo una carpeta llamada `custodias`. Dentro de esa carpeta tengo 4 archivos php y cada uno tiene cargado `session start();`

Cuando los ejecuto directamente me regresan al index debido a que tengo seteada la sesión del nombre del usuario; si no la encuentra, lo redirecciona al index.

Tengo otra subcarpeta con varios códigos php los cuales también tienen `session_start();` pero si estos los ejecuto en el navegador ingresando la ruta del archivo si se ejecutan.

¿Existe alguna manera de evitar que se ejecuten los php o se oculten las carpetas en un LAMP?

Comment: Por favor actualiza tu pregunta añadiendo código fuente de tu proyecto PHP. _Si entendí bien tu pregunta_, ¿lo que quieres es evitar el acceso a páginas que no estén logueados, es decir, la validación de la autenticación de un usuario?

Comment: He intentado cubrir en mi respuesta todos los casos que pienso que estás tratando de solucionar. Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según he entendido tu problema se puede dividir en dos problemas con diferente solución:

- Detectar que el usuario no está autenticado para redirigirlo a la pantalla de entrada si trata de acceder a un script PHP de manera directa.
- Impedir que se pueda listar el contenido de un directorio que no contiene un archivo `index.php` o `index.html` en él.
- Impedir ejecución de archivos PHP de utilidades de manera directa conociendo la ruta a ellos.

---

**Control de usuario autenticado**

La función [`session_start()`](http://php.net/session_start) sólo inicia las funciones de carga y salvado automático de las variables de sesión, gestión de la cookie de sesión, etc.

En ningún caso te redirige por si sola al índice en caso de no tener iniciada la sesión, eso debes programarlo tú mismo.

Para empezar debes conocer qué se guarda en la variable súper global `$_SESSION` para hacer alguna comprobación tipo.

Ejemplo de comprobación para enviar al formulario de inicio de sesión:

```php
/* Comprobamos la validez de la sesión y que el usuario está autenticado */
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['autenticado'] || $_SESSION['autenticado'] !== true) {
  header('Location: /entrada.php');
  die();
}
```

En el archivo `entrada.php` debes tener algún sitio donde guardas los datos del usuario de esta manera:

```php
/* Cuando comprobamos que el usuario y contraseña es correcto... */
$_SESSION['autenticado'] = true;
```

Y cuando cierres la sesión, antes de borrar cookies, destruir la sesión, etc es recomendable hacer un [`unset()`](http://php.net/unset) o poner a `false` su contenido:

```php
/* Cualquiera de las dos opciones: */
$_SESSION['autenticado'] = false;
unset($_SESSION['autenticado']);
```

---

**Impedir listado de archivos**

Para evitar que tu servidor `apache` muestre el contenido o listado de directorio debes crear un archivo `.htaccess` que tenga este contenido (o agregarlo al que ya exista):

```
Options -Indexes
```

También puedes poner eso mismo en la declaración `<Directory>` de tu raíz web (en `apache.conf` o el archivo de configuración donde teclas declarada la configuración de tu sitio web).

Otra solución (igual de válida pero siempre puedes olvidar algún directorio por error) es crear un archivo `index.html` vacío en cada directorio en el que quieras impedir que aparezca el listado de archivos.

---

**Impedir ejecución de scripts PHP de manera directa**

En algunos ocasiones desarrollamos una página con varios archivos PHP que se llaman unos a otros con `require` o `include` y queremos impedir que puedan ejecutarlos sin permiso.

Para ello hay tres soluciones:

- La más elegante: poner los archivos PHP fuera del raíz del sitio web como hacen la mayoría de frameworks.
- Usando un directorio para bibliotecas de funciones: ponemos un `.htaccess` que contenga `deny from all`. Provocará que cualquier intento de acceder a ellos de manera directa desde el navegador nos muestre un [Error 403 - Denied](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403).
- La más chapucera: hacer un `define('ESTOY_DENTRO', 1);` al principio de todos los PHP en los que permites ejecución directa y un `if (defined('ESTOY_DENTRO') === false) die();` en los que no. Si un PHP se llama desde otro autorizado esa condición no se cumplirá y se ejecutará el código. En caso de intentar acceder a él de manera directa no aparecerá nada, finalizará su ejecución inmediatamente.

Espero que te sean de ayuda todas las opciones explicadas.

EDITO: En esta otra respuesta he ampliado cada uno de los casos con código y ejemplos:

- [Ejecutar ficheros .php solo desde otros ficheros .php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/184850/ejecutar-ficheros-php-solo-desde-otros-ficheros-php/187763#187763)

Comment: Excelente tus buenos argumentos y gran conocimiento. Me sirvió para evitar  ejecutar un PHP dentro del navegador.