# Ejecutar ficheros PHP sólo desde otros ficheros PHP

Tags: php, html, seguridad

Estoy haciendo un sitio web y me gustaría saber cómo hacer para que los archivos PHP se ejecuten sólo si son llamados desde otros archivos PHP. Es decir, que no se puedan ejecutar de manera directa desde el navegador.

He visto la siguiente pregunta respondida por [OscarGarcia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18608/oscargarcia) en la que recomienda algunas cosas:

- [Evitar ejecutar código PHP directamente en el navegador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/47675/evitar-ejecutar-c%C3%B3digo-php-directamente-en-el-navegador)

Entre ellas indica lo siguiente:

- Poner los archivos PHP fuera del directorio raiz del sitio web. Esto no termino de entenderlo, ¿Se refiere fuera del directorio que sirve el contenido web? si es así, ¿se puede llamar al archivo PHP?
- Se indica el uso de `.htaccess` para incluir en el la linea: `deny from all`. Esto evita la ejecución directa y la ejecución desde otro archivo PHP.
- Indica también `if (defined('ESTOY_DENTRO') === false) die();` en los ficheros que no se quiere que se ejecuten de manera directa. Esto también me evita que se ejecuten desde otro archivo PHP.

¿Alguna sugerencia para ayudarme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amplío aquí (y probablemente relacione la pregunta anterior con ésta) la explicación de las recomendaciones que hice.

Pongamos la siguiente estructura de código almacenando funciones en el subdirectorio `src` dentro de `/var/www/html` de un servidor, configurada dicha ruta como [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/core.html#documentroot):

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/html/src/archivo1.php
/var/www/html/src/archivo2.php
```

El archivo `index.php` puede incluir `archivo1.php` y `archivo2.php` de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/src/archivo1.php';
include __DIR__ . '/src/archivo2.php';
```

Pero si la URL de la aplicación es `https://ejemplo/index.php` entonces las siguientes URLs podrán ejecutar de manera directa dichos archivos PHP:

```
https://ejemplo/src/archivo1.php
https://ejemplo/src/archivo2.php
```

Esto es precisamente lo que el autor original quiere evitar. Ahora veamos las soluciones.

### Poner los archivos PHP fuera del directorio raíz del sitio web

> Esto no termino de entenderlo, ¿Se refiere fuera del directorio que sirve el contenido web? si es así, ¿se puede llamar al archivo PHP?

Esta solución es la más recomendable y es la que usan la mayoría de frameworks PHP.

Cambiamos la estructura de directorios a la siguiente:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/html_publico/
/var/www/html/html_publico/index.php
/var/www/html/src/archivo1.php
/var/www/html/src/archivo2.php
```

Notar que es importante cambiar la ruta raíz del servidor web (`DocumentRoot`) para que sea `/var/www/html/html_publico/` en vez de `/var/www/html/`.

En este escenario el archivo `index.php` seguirá siendo accesible a través de `https://ejemplo/index.php`, pero ya no es posible acceder a ninguna URL del servidor web para cargar los PHP de manera directa:

```
https://ejemplo/../src/archivo1.php
https://ejemplo/src/archivo1.php
https://ejemplo/../src/archivo2.php
https://ejemplo/src/archivo2.php
```

Ahora, para compensar el cambio realizado en la ruta donde está el `index.php`, la inclusión de los archivos se realizaría de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/../src/archivo1.php';
include __DIR__ . '/../src/archivo2.php';
```

Que sube un nivel en la estructura de directorios y desde allí accede al subdirectorio `src`, que a nivel de ejecución del script PHP sí que sigue disponible (sigue siendo un archivo local).

### Se indica el uso de `.htaccess` para incluir en el la linea: `deny from all`

> Esto evita la ejecución directa y la ejecución desde otro archivo PHP.

Impide la ejecución directa, pero se puede seguir incluyendo desde otro archivo PHP como de costumbre. Es una restricción de acceso a nivel de servidor web, no de ejecución de PHP.

La estructura quedaría así:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/html/src/.htaccess
/var/www/html/src/archivo1.php
/var/www/html/src/archivo2.php
```

De modo que el archivo `.htaccess` protege la carga directa únicamente el contenido del directorio `src`.

La inclusión de archivos no se ve alterada porque no hemos reorganizado el contenido:

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/src/archivo1.php';
include __DIR__ . '/src/archivo2.php';
```

### `if (defined('ESTOY_DENTRO') === false) die();` en los ficheros que no se quiere que se ejecuten de manera directa

> Esto también me evita que se ejecuten desde otro archivo PHP.

No, sólo evita que se carge desde otro archivo PHP que no haya definido previamente el `define` necesario.

Ejemplo con esta estructura de archivos:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/html/index2.php
/var/www/html/src/.htaccess
/var/www/html/src/archivo1.php
/var/www/html/src/archivo2.php
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
define('ESTOY_DENTRO', 1);
include __DIR__ . '/src/archivo1.php'
include __DIR__ . '/src/archivo2.php'
/* Resto del código */
```

**index2.php**

```
<?php
include __DIR__ . '/src/archivo1.php'
include __DIR__ . '/src/archivo2.php'
/* Resto del código */
```

**archivo1.php** y **archivo2.php**

```
<?php
if (defined('ESTOY_DENTRO') === false) die();
/* Resto del código */
```

En este caso la inclusión de `archivo1.php` y `archivo2.php` desde `index.php` funcionará correctamente, pero la inclusión desde `index2.php` fallará y finalizará la ejecución del PHP.

Podría tener utilidad para limitar las llamadas de unos PHP desde otros, pero siendo los desarrolladores los únicos que pueden cambiar el código de la aplicación, eso debería hacerse de manera consciente y no mediante este tipo de controles.

---

Espero que esta explicación ampliada te haya sido de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia me ha servido de ayuda y me ha aclarado muchas cosillas.

Answer (score 2):

- Al acceder a una aplicación mediante la url, modificando la url solo se puede acceder dentro de la aplicación es decir `localhost/app/carpeta`, sin embargo no puedes salir a fuera de esta y aun intentando lo de forma cutre `localhost/app/../../../` se puede intentar pero lo único que llegas es al localhost. Aun asi desde un fichero php si que puedes indicar otra posicion fuera del proyecto; `include "../../aplicacion2/fichero.php"` es decir, sales de la carpeta de tu proyecto y entras/incluyes otro fichero que este fuera de este. Esta opcion no es muy practica por varias razones:

  1. Todos los fichero que quieres proteger tienen que estar en esta otro proyecto
  2. A la hora de mover el proyecto tienes que mover ambas carpetas
  3. Dependiendo del servidor puede no te permita salir fuera del directorio de la aplicacion.

- Denny from all se utiliza para evitar el acceso desde fuera del servidor,pero desde local o la aplicación si que se puede.
- Esta opción se refiere a declarar una variable antes de hacer el include(aunque esta un poco mal explicado), por lo tanto compruebas si la variable existe y si resulta que no significa que no ha sido un include( Aunque este metodo tiene fallas de seguridad, se explica mas en cuestión en este [post, los comentarios de la primera respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php)

**SOLUCION:**
Un arreglo bastante sencillo que se me ha ocurrido es utilizando `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` esto te devuelve te devuelve la uri utilizada para acceder al fichero, es decir si por defecto para acceder a tu fichero utilizas `datos.php` te deolvera como uri: `/datos.php` o si utilizas directorio `/datos/index.php` y accedes mediante `/datos/` la variable contendra `/datos/`.
Utilizando este metodo pudes añadir esto en tus ficheros include:

```
<?php
    $origen = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
    if($origen!= "/datos/?algo"){
        header("location:../error/");
        die();
    }
?>
```

Con estas lineas de codigo todo aquello que no acceda a la url con `?algo`
al final sera redireccionado, por lo tanto al hacer el include simplemente añades `?algo` al final.

> Espero que no haga falta, pero por si acaso :D 
> `"algo"` puede ser cualquier otro string, numero o caracter

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Perdona pero sigo un poco verde en esto todavía. Con respecto a la solución que me indicas, antes de realizar la llamada a cualquier archivo PHP tendría que obtener  url para luego hacer la comprobación al principio de cada código de PHP?

Comment: Ese codigo php lo incluyes en todos los archivos que quieras proteger. La variable `$origen` obtiene la url mediante la cual se ha accedido al fichero .php por lo tanto al añadir `?algo` no impactas la pagina pero la variable si que lo registra y comprueba si coincide o no, Sabiendo esto pones el texto que tu quieras  como clave despues del `?` y cuando alguien o algo accede al archivo y la url no contiene dicho texto, sera redirigido a otro sitio. Por lo tanto para acceder a este fichero tienes que añadirle la terminación `?secreto` o si no lo rechazara,se aplica también a los includes

Comment: Perdona pero te voy a hacer una preguntilla... El primer archivo PHP que se ejecuta es a partir de un HTML, es decir a partir de un botón. Como la llamada al fichero PHP no la hago con un `include` no puedo pasarle el contenido de `$origen` (o al menos entiendo eso). Se le podría pasar de alguna manera?? GRACIAS!!

Comment: y necesitas que este primer php tampoco sea accesible si nos es por el boton? porque sino simplemente no incluyes la comprobación en este y listo

Comment: Y no solo es con includes, es con todo, si añades ese codigo a un archivo php, e intentas acceder manualmente a la url, a menos que añadas "?secreto" seras redireccionado

Comment: Aunque no es obligatorio si sería conveniente (me gustaría saber si se puede hacer). Este primer PHP hace `include` para llamar a otros archivos (estos si necesito que NO sean accesibles). He estado trasteando la solución que me has comentado y en principio me está funcionando bien, si llamas directamente a los archivos te redirige. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Así a primeras y viendo que no es tan importante como el resto podrías simplemente ejecutar el mismo método solo, que ponerle otro texto diferente de verificación; `href=primero.php?s1`, O sino  también se podría simular un POST con un formulario oculto, en todo caso en ambos se puede ver el link y el paramento mediante las herramientas de desarrollador. Se podría hacer un método mucho mas complejo usando `$_SESSION` aunque no creo que haga falta complicarse tanto, con ponerle otro parametro diferente a `$origen` te redirecionara todo a menos que alguien estudie el href del HTML

Comment: Un apunte: la línea `header("location:../error/");` redirige al usuario a la URL `/error/` **TRAS EJECUTAR** el resto del script PHP. Para que finalice la ejecución deberías incluir un `die()`, `return` o `exit()` después del `header`.  Además, mantener esa comprobación en múltiples archivos PHP es engorroso y dificulta cambiar el punto de entrada a la aplicación (debes cambiar toooodos los archivos).

Comment: Aún así te llevas mi +1 por la explicación :)

Comment: @OscarGarcia Suelo hacer uso del `die();` pero se me escapo en esta ocasión :), Aun así respecto a lo otro , es la manera mas sencilla de hacer que se me ocurrió al momento ya que al final, me parece mas efectivo poner 3 lineas de codigo  que los  las 3 alternativas mencionadas por el OP por las razones que enumero en la respuesta. Y tendria que probarlo pero  creo que seria posible hasta resumirlo a un `require "seguridadInclude.php";` que conetenga esas lineas de codigo

Comment: `REQUEST_URI` puede proteger una única URL, pero ¿qué ocurre si el usuario navega a una nueva URL? Prácticamente todos los frameworks tienen un único script PHP de entrada (un `index.php` en el `DocumentRoot`) y las secciones se acceden mediante parámetros GET diferentes. La solución de usar `define()`, tal y como puse en la respuesta original a la que hace referencia (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340001/deny-direct-access-to-all-php-files-except-index-php) la considero "chapuza" y está en desuso porque te obliga a desplegar ese código o el `require "seguridadInclude.php"` sin olvido.